# Cardinal of the quotient set

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. In $X \times X$ define the equivalence
$(a,b)\:\mathcal{R}\:(c,d)$ if $a+b=c+d$. Then what is the cardinal of the quotient set?

I know that $|X| = 9$, so $| X \times X | = |X| |X| = 81$. But how use the relation for the cardinal of the quotient set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $r = a+b$ with $a,b\in X$

How many different values can $r$ have?

Comment: I think that r has 81 different values, not?

Comment: @rgl4 No, note that $1+4 = 2+3 = 3+2 = 4+1$ so we count the value $r = 5$ once.

Hint: The lowest value $r$ can have is $2$ since $1+1 = 2$ and the highest is $18$ since $9+9 = 18$

Comment: So, the answer to my exercise is 17 not?

Comment: @rgl4 Yes! There are $17$ subsets $S_r$ of $X\times X$ that form a partition so that if $(a,b), (c,d)\in S_r$ then $a+b = c+d$